# Linux File Descriptor logs

Tags: linux, file-descriptor

One of my java build process in Linux machine is running slow of late. One of the things i suspect causing slowness is the process hitting the max file descriptor limit. I don't have permission to find out how many file descriptors are being used by my build process. So, does Linux log in a file if a process hits the max file descriptor limit, which i can check to see if my build process is slowing because of the max file descriptor limit.

Answer (score 0):

check `/proc/PIDOFPROCESS/fd/`. This contains all the open descriptors used by the program. `ls ..dir.. | wc -l` will give you the number.

`ulimit -n` will give you the maximum number of open descriptors. You can also set this value before running the program.

Comment: Well, i don't have access to /proc/PID/fd directory, so i could not check the count

Comment: well, you can still raise the limit (if you have permission :)) and see whether it fixes the problem..

Comment: I don't have permission to raise the limit. I can request my admin to raise the limit, but i was wondering if such error (max file descriptor limit per process) is logged some where, which i can show to my admin and request raising the limit.